# Can a 60" x 30" x 79" shower/tub fit through 36 door?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tub

I am looking at tub showers from Aquatic.  I don't see a lot of choices that offer shelves...but I am also budget shopping.  I found a couple I think I'd be happy with.

I'd like to get a one piece unit if it fits. I have standard 36" doors in my house.  I don't know for sure tub measurements but is the size the exterior dimension or interior?  I know 30" will fit through a 36" door barely unless the door is completely hinged 180 degrees and out of the opening.

They also offer the same model in 76" height and I don't understand what the difference in those 3 inches for height is all about?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you _sure_ you have 36" doors all the way into the bathroom?  A 36" door for a bathroom would be very large, unless it was specifically made ADA compliant.  Sorry to be obvious, but I assumed and bought the wrong door.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yes, I am building my house and made my R.O. to accommodate 36" doors everywhere besides closets.

Comment: A standard 30"x60" tub fits into a 30"x60" opening, so I would _assume_ the measurements are outside, and would be very surprised if they were inside measurements.  Not posting as answer, because I've never purchased/installed one.

Comment: Is the bathroom already finished?  That is, would it be hard to remove studs temporarily?

Comment: @wallyk - its only framed. I would have to use my recip saw on the doorway stud to get a better turning radius.  The tubs are from aquatic and only one is a one piece, the other two I like are 2 piece or 4 piece.

Answer (score 3):

Yes these should fit into any opening that is a half inch wider (tub measurements are for the outside).  However there are tubs that have a curvy outside shell or step-layers.  If your tub has something like this I would assume that extra width is not part of the tub width.  You can usually tell with a picture of the tub.

However we hardly ever bring tubs in via doors when doing a build.  We would simply just not nail in certain framing.  Then knock over the 2x4s, let the tub pass through (might do this for multiple walls and sometimes the only door we use is the front door), then nail up the framing after done.  This is just easier and keeps tub from being scratched up.

Comment: Yep.  The flip side to framing around them is that I'll be cutting one up with a sawzall to get it out of my bathroom pretty soon...

Answer (score 0):

If it is an existing door in the frame, you will have to drive out the hinge pins, (top one last), and remove the door to get the full width available. 
the door stops may still reduce the size by 3/4" to 1" i.e. 35-1/4" max opening with stops.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to go with a Sterling - Vikrell 4-piece or an Aquatic 1 piece.  I have heard the Sterling (Vikrell material) is superior in multi-piece technology in terms of locking together and not leaking.  I am hesitant about the 1 piece from Aquatic because it only has a 5 year warranty versus 10, and it's about $250 cheaper.  My concern is it may have a lesser quality finish.  I'm pretty sure I can fit a one piece in by removing the trimmer+jack stud on my rough opening, but am unsure if the tub quality is as good as the Vikrell.  I'll think on it some more.